# sqldeveloper can't start

Tags: bash, java

When starting *sqldeveloper* it crashes without any warning. It just shows a window for a fraction of second.
By debuging :

```
$ bash -vx /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper
```

it gives this trace :

```
+ exitCode=1
+ ProductCanRestart
+ '[' X = X ']'
+ return 1
+ CanRestart=1
+ '[' 1 = 0 ']'
+ '[' 1 = 245 ']'
+ '[' 1 -gt 0 ']'
${JAVA} -version 2>&1
++ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/dt.jar -version
+ s='java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~trusty1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)'
expr "$s" : 'java version \"1\.[0-3]'
++ expr 'java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~trusty1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)' : 'java version \"1\.[0-3]'
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
expr "$s" : 'java version \"1\.[0-7].*\"'
++ expr 'java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~trusty1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)' : 'java version \"1\.[0-7].*\"'
+ '[' 23 -le 0 ']'
+ return 1
```

Addictional information :

```
$ grep -i jvm ~/.sqldeveloper/4.0.0/product.conf
SetJavaHome /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

$ uname -a
Linux yakrif 3.13.0-27-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 15 18:06:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Sounds like a vendor problem. "return 1" just means it crashed. Response code '0' would be OK. Other data seems to be just telling you what versions of java you are using. Make sure your java versions are compatible, that is all I can come up with based on this.

Comment: I copied sqldeveloper and jdk from a "well working" system with a similar architecture but it gives the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an issue I had with it, I needed to modify `sql_developer/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh` and added the following line as line 2:

```
unset GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
```

Unfortunately I can not remember the reference where I found it, otherwise I mentioned it here.

Comment: A such variable is not defined. I don't use GNOME but XFCE.

Comment: Ok, perhaps XFCE has a similar variable. I found my reference: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2598309. Maybe it can help you investigating your issue.